# Change children class when clicking on parent element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a more efficient way with angular to change or add a class to the children of a parent element when the parent is being clicked, other then getting all the childNodes within a function and adding a class for each child ?

```
<div class="menu-icon-container" ng-click="changeState()">
    <div ng-repeat="bar in [bar1, bar2, bar3] track by $index" class="bar{{$index + 1}} "></div>
</div>
```

The desired result is when `menu-icon-container` is clicked, the divs within it will toggle a class based on a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-style` directive for this. Just set a property on the $scope which you can toggle on click on the `div.menu-icon-container`

```
<div class="menu-icon-container" ng-click="conditionForClassName = !conditionForClassName">
  <div ng-repeat="bar in [bar1, bar2, bar3] track by $index" 
    ng-class="{ 'className': conditionForClassName }"></div>
</div>
```

[Docs for ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 1):

you can use directives

**DIRECTIVE**

```
 myApp.directive('addClassChild', function($timeout) {
   var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < element[0].children.length+1; i++) {
           element.children().eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
      });
   };
return {
   link: linkFn,
   restrict: 'A',
};
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-icon-container" add-class-child>
    <div ng-repeat="bar in [bar1, bar2, bar3] " class="bar{{$index + 1}} ">
      {{$index}}
    </div>
</div>
```

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children.